# Relay RANGE_ADD queryConfig on SearchType

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs

I'm trying to understand what config should be used for `RANGE_ADD` mutation if `parent` of the new item is something like `SearchType` which doesn't have an ID attribute.
What should be used as `parentId` in this case or how this mutation should be configured? If I don't specify `parentID` then newly created item won't be added to the Relay store.

I've read lots of issue in Relay repo but it's still unclear to me how to handle this mutation properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case creating `SearchType` object with an static id would work. This is an example using graphql-ruby but the concept should work in any implementations:

https://github.com/gauravtiwari/relay-rails-blog/blob/8b257c3d32b7ef9d1aab4420257d8b6471006d0a/app/models/viewer.rb

And client side implementation would look like:

```
class SearchPostMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation {searchPosts}`;
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      // For debug, you can hard code your SearchType object's id here. 
      id: 'SA9bdDbpc4QtwzppZD0+IbJsE4QgzQ==',
    };
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'RANGE_ADD',
      parentName: 'searchPost',
      // For debug, you can hard code your SearchType object's id here. 
      parentID: 'SA9bdDbpc4QtwzppZD0+IbJsE4QgzQ==',
      connectionName: 'posts',
      edgeName: 'newPostEdge',
      rangeBehaviors: {
        '': 'prepend',
      },
    }];
  }
}
```